# Minmum Key Length for Block Ciphers Required keeping in view futuristic quantum computers

Tags: keys

In an answer to the Question "[What are recommended, general strategies to start block-cipher design and/or analysis?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39791/what-are-recommended-general-strategies-to-start-block-cipher-design-and-or-ana?noredirect=1&lq=1)", in terms of brute force attack, it is written

> 256 bits is considered secure forever, even in the face of futuristic
>   quantum computers

is it true? or i can consider 128 or 192 bits secure as well keeping in view the futuristic quantum computers? or it should be more than 256 bits?

Comment: It is my personal opinion, that for quantum-proofing (forever), you need 576-bits.

Comment: [Relevant (recent) paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/811) which says that the time-2 strategy for quantum-proofing is quite heavily on the conservative side of things.

Comment: so to be on safe side just double the symmetric key length?