# What are the general rules to follow if I want to design a block cipher suitable for file encryption?

Tags: block-cipher, file-encryption

Can you please tell me what should be the quality of an encryption function using a key size of 256 bits...
I realized from my previous question that a simple XOR of plaintext (256 bits) with a suitable key of same size is totally unsafe, as the key  can be totally recovered by a simple known plaintext attack. 
I was trying to implement my own cipher as a project for fun !
Thankyou everyone in advance... !

Comment: [Does this Q&A your question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/39791/23623)?

Comment: @SEJPM Thankyou for that !

Answer (score 0):

Block cipher design is hard.

In my opinion, the most accurate description of a quality would be "withstand public cryptanalysis for a couple of years, while there is enough public interest".